# MySQL alias a query for use in another query

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

My title isn't great, but let me explain my situation.  I have a `jobs` table.  The jobs table has 2 foreign keys to the `users` table: `sales_rep_id` and `account_manager_id`.

Then I have another table called `contact_info` with a one to one relationship to the users table.

```
jobs
-----
sales_rep_id
account_manager_id
...

users
-----
first_name
last_name

contact_info
-----
user_id
home_phone
```

If I want to do a query where I get the phone number for both people on every job I would do the following:

```
SELECT reps.home_phone as reps_home, account_managers.home_phone as a_m_home FROM jobs
JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM users 
   JOIN contact_info 
   ON users.id = contact_info.user_id) reps
ON reps.id = jobs.sales_rep_id
JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM users 
   JOIN contact_info 
   ON users.id = contact_info.user_id) account_managers
ON account_managers.id = jobs.account_manager_id
```

Is there anything I can do to create a temporary table with the joined data?  What is the most efficient way to do this join? For example, what if I had 10 foreign keys in the jobs table to the users table, and I needed the phone_number for all 10?

Comment: You could define a view that joins the two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be obtain all the info you need

```
SELECT j.*
 , u1.first_name as sales_rep_first_name
 , u1.last_name as sales_reps_last_name
 , u2.first_name as manager_first_name
 , u2.u1.last_name as manager_last_name
 , c1.home_phone as sales_rep_home_phone
 , c2.home_phone as manager_home_phone
FROM jobs as j
INNER JOIN contact_info as c1 ON j.sales_rep_id = c1.user_id
INNER JOIN user u1 ON u1.id= c1.user_id
INNER JOIN contact_info as c2 ON j.saccount_manager_id = c2.user_id
INNER JOIN user u2 ON u2.id= c2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a view that joins `user` and `contact_info`.

```
CREATE VIEW user_contact_info
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.home_phone
FROM user AS u
JOIN contact_info AS c ON u.id = c.user_id
```

Then you can use this as if it's a table.

```
SELECT reps.home_phone as reps_home, account_managers.home_phone as a_m_home 
FROM jobs
JOIN user_contact_info AS reps ON reps.id = jobs.sales_rep_id
JOIN user_contact_info AS account_managers ON account_managers.id = jobs.account_manager_id
```